# Display image from Uri

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, uri

In a Windows Phone 8 app, I'm using the following code to display an image:

```
InitializeComponent();
Image i = new Image();
i.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\Data\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\sample_photo_05.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));       
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(i);
```

But when the page loads, the screen is empty. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Put the image inside the solution.

Comment: What if i want to use photo from /Camera Roll? or just taking picture from camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy your image in Asset folder and set Build Action==Content

```
Image i = new Image();
i.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/yourProjectName;component/Assets/YourImageName", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));       
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(i);
```

Comment: use this it would helpful

Comment: What if i want to use photo from /Camera Roll? or just taking picture from camera?

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps to set image by URI in windows phone
   1. Copy Image in Images folder in your solution.
   2. Set Image as Resource    Rightclick on Image->Properties->Build Action ==Content

```
InitializeComponent();
Image i = new Image();
i.Height =100;
i.Width=100;
i.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/YourImageName", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));       
 LayoutRoot.Children.Add(i);
```

Comment: What if i want to use photo from /Camera Roll? or just taking picture from camera?

Answer (score 1):

Using a CameraCaptureTask, May be like this

initialize a CameraCaptureTask Object

```
 CameraCaptureTask cameracapturetask = new CameraCaptureTask();
                    cameracapturetask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(cameracapturetask_Completed);
                    cameracapturetask.Show();
```

and inside its event

```
void cameracapturetask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
                {
                    BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
                    bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
                    img.Source = bmp;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy your image in a folder (Images) and set Build Action==Content

```
// draw an image, set relative source (in project) and add to LayoutRoot.
var i = new Image{
Source = new BitmapImage(
new Uri("/project;component/Images/image.jpg", UriKind.Relative))
};       
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(i);
```